# what's the best way to send a user_id over to a separate rails service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services

Say I have a big rails app running at https://www.acme.com and I want to make a new rails app running at https://billing.acme.com.  The point of breaking this billing service out into it's own rails app is:

1. want to be able to deploy changes to it independent of releases to the main www rails app
2. want to stop adding code to our main www rails app because it's already so big

When a logged in user clicks over to https://billing.acme.com what's the best way to identify the logged in user?  Read the cookie because it's the same domain just a different subdomain?  Send over a token because reading the cookie is a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [Rails Tutorial for Subdomains with Devise](http://railsapps.github.io/tutorial-rails-subdomains.html).

As for sending a `user_id` back and forth, you may want your subdomain app to access your main app through its API.